# Mouse won't work at startup when running classic gnome-failsafe desktop and auto-login

Tags: 11.10, mouse, gnome-classic, auto-login

I've got a laptop with Ubuntu 11.10 with classic gnome-failsafe desktop and auto-login set up. Sometimes, when I start the laptop and after typing in the gnome-keyring password, the touchpad cursor won't work. But if then I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to log-out, and login again, the touchpad will work fine.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!